# How to use Tweepy to stream Tweets using arabic text as query using Python?

Tags: python, twitter, unicode, streaming, tweepy

I have been trying to stream Tweets using Tweepy. While it works just fine when the query is in English I cannot get it to work when the query is in Arabic. From previous questions I tried twitterStream.filter(track=[u'الإسلامية']) as unicode but got the error:

```
In[36]: twitterStream.filter(track=[u'الإسلامية'])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3032, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-35-706cbc790f1e>", line 1, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2978, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3049, in run_code
    self.showtraceback()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5\helpers\pydev\pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 144, in showtraceback
    import traceback;traceback.print_exc()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 233, in print_exc
    print_exception(etype, value, tb, limit, file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 125, in print_exception
    print_tb(tb, limit, file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 70, in print_tb
    if line: _print(file, '    ' + line.strip())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\traceback.py", line 13, in _print
    file.write(str+terminator)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 34-42: character maps to <undefined>
```

If am somewhat desperate at this point to figure this out.

My code:

```
__author__ = 'Janis'
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python


import tweepy
import time

# Initialize tweepy functions------------------------------------------------
CONSUMER_KEY =''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ''


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

class Listener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print status.text
        return True

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print 'Error in streaming'
        print status_code

        pass


keyword = 'ISIL'

twitterStream =tweepy.Stream(auth=auth, listener=Listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=[u'الإسلامية'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `twitterStream.filter(track=[unicode("الإسلامية", "utf-8")])`

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
print status.text
return True
```

use:

```
print('{}\t{}\t{}'.format(status.created_at,status.user.screen_name,status.text))
```